# Diametrl path of a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G(V,E)$ be a graph. A path whose length is equal to the diameter of a graph is called a **diametral** path. In a cycle graph every vertex has $2$ diametral paths. Now I need to prove that this:

> If each $v \in V(G) $ has the same number of diametral paths initiated from it, then $G$ is a regular graph.

Comment: Interesting! Where did you encounter this problem? Do you know this to be true?

Comment: Yes it is true!.

Comment: Ah, that helps. :-) Still haven't a clue, though. If this problem is included as an exercise in a certain textbook (or lecture notes or something like that), I would be very interested in seeing that particular textbook. Maybe it contains helpful theorems that I'm currently unaware of. I didn't find anything like this in my graph theory textbooks. (Maybe it requires techniques from algebraic graph theory, or linear algebra? Or maybe there is a combinatorial proof, and we just didn't try hard enough. :P Admittedly, I only thought about it for a short time.)

Comment: Its my research topic and it is not there in any text book.

Comment: Ah, I see. Too bad!

Answer (score 1):

For the above problem I got the counter example from the following link.
https://mathoverflow.net/a/239446/78180